# one or zero to many relationship WebAPI

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have two entities

**Subject**

```
  public class Subject
  {
     public int SubjectId { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags{ get; set; }
  }
```

**Tag**

```
  public class Tag
  {
     public int TagId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

These two entities have a one or zero to many relationship.
I define relation between two entities as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().HasMany(p => p.Tags)
    .WithMany().Map(x =>
    {
            x.MapLeftKey("SubjectId");
            x.MapRightKey("TagId");
            x.ToTable("Subject_Tag");
    });
```

First I create Tags, but when I edit Subject to add Tags, the database creates another tag and links to it, meaning that it creates duplicate tags with same name.
What's the problem?

my edit controller(i use UnitOfWork Repository)

```
    [ModelValidator]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(SubjectFullDto dto)
    {
        try
        {
            SubjectExists();
            var subjectEntity = ModelFactory.GetSubject(dto);
            var subject = UnitOfWork.SubjectRepository.Update(subjectEntity);
            var model = ModelFactory.GetLigthSubject(subject);
            return Ok(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            #if DEBUG
            return InternalServerError(ex);
            #endif
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

and in Modal Factory:

```
public Subject GetSubject(SubjectFullDto obj)
    {
        var alltags = _unitOfWork.SubjectTagRepository.Get();
        var org_tags = new HashSet<int>(org_subject.Tags.Select(c => c.ID));
        var new_tag = new HashSet<int>(obj.Tags.Select(c => c.Uid));
        foreach (var item in alltags)
        {
            if (new_tag.Contains(item.ID))
            {
                if (!org_tags.Contains(item.ID))
                {
                    org_subject.Tags.Add(item); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (org_tags.Contains(item.ID))
                {
                    org_subject.Tags.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

at first in this situation you should create tag class without identity id:

```
public class Tag
  {
     [Key]
     public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

db don`t save duplicate tag in database,
 in your edit action :

```
if (model.tag!= null)
    subject.tag= model.tag.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => new tag() { Name= x }).ToList();
```

Comment: InnerException = {"Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Tag' with unique index 'NameIndex'. The duplicate key value is (unitedstate).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: i set tagname as [Index("NameIndex", IsUnique = true)]
        public String Name { get; set; }